# How to inherit from a module specified by an argument

Tags: python, metaclass

Say I have several version of APIs, each have same interface (attributes and function names), they are designed to be inherited in my custom class and rewrite the **OnCallback** function.

```
# api1.py
class API:
    version='1.0'
    
    def OnCallback(self, msg):
        pass
```

```
# api2.py
class API:
    version='2.0'

    def OnCallback(self, msg):
        pass
```

Usually, if theres's no other version, it's quite simple to write my own handler like

```
# handler.py
from api1 import API  # but which api version is unknown here

class Handler(API):
    def __init__(self, version, *args):  # actually, Handler need to be inherited by this version
        super().__init__(*args):
        print(self.version)
        
    def OnCallback(self, msg):
        print(msg)
```

this Handler is able to deal with all versions of APIs, the differences lies in the API backend itselves.

But I need to determine which one to inherit by a given argument **version**, meaning I need to use importlib.import_module to import the specific version and a Metaclass to pass the api class, I guess.

So far, I came up with a not-so-perfect solution, like:

```
from importlib import import_module
from api1 import API  # import api1.API as a standard ver


def get_handler(version, account):
    return type('Handler', (import_module(version).API, _Handler), {})(account)


class _Handler(API):  # add api1.API as a standard ver to inherit, making pycharm available to find base declarations to go to
    def __init__(self, account):
        self.account = account

    def OnCallback(self, msg):
        print(self.version, self.account, msg)  # otherwise, self.version would be marked PyUnresolvedReferences
```

Here I got

```
___________________________________
handler = get_handler('api2', 'account1')
handler.account
Out[3]: 'account1'
handler.ver
Out[4]: '2.0'
```

which is correct.

But passing api1 to `get_handler` would raise TypeError: Cannot create a consistent method resolution
order (MRO) for bases API, Handler
because it's inherited duplicated.
I can still remove `(API)` in `class _Handler(API):`, but it would
bring up lots of refference warning and make me dificault to write class methods.

Is there any better practice?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I think that using `importlib` is the best choice here.
I would implement it like so:

```
import importlib

class Handler:
    def __init__(self, version, *args):
        api_module = importlib.import_module(f'api{version.replace(".", "")}')
        self.api = api_module.API(*args)
        print(self.api.version)

    def OnCallback(self, msg):
        self.api.OnCallback(msg)
```

and then creating the `Handler` instance:

```
handler = Handler('1.0') # or 2.0
handler.OnCallback('Hello, World!')
```

Comment: I think wrap the api inside this handler instead of inherit is 'one way hook', meaning something (message) envoked handler.OnCallback can trigger the processing by the api. But in this case, the message is triggered INSIDE the api itself, and the processing is doing nothing. That is why this api need to be inherited.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Based on the question details (`version='2.0'` can only be passed to the `__init__` or `__new__` method), then a rough implementation to make this work is as follows. The basic idea is to dynamically create **but cache a new subclass** between `Handler` and whatever `API` version based on the passed `version` string.

```py
from __future__ import annotations

import typing as tp

import importlib


if tp.TYPE_CHECKING:
    import types

    from api1 import API  # import api1.API as a standard ver
else:
    API = object


# Global cache to prevent more than one attempt to dynamically
# create API subclasses of the same version
_VERSION_TO_MIXED_API_CLASS: dict[str, type[Handler]] = {}


class Handler(API):
    def __new__(cls, version: str, *args: object) -> Handler:
        mixed_class: type[Handler] | None = _VERSION_TO_MIXED_API_CLASS.get(version)
        if mixed_class is None:
            versioned_api_module: types.ModuleType = importlib.import_module(
                f"api{version[:version.find('.')]}"
            )
            assert hasattr(versioned_api_module, "API") and isinstance(
                versioned_api_module.API, type
            )
            mixed_class = type(cls.__qualname__, (cls, versioned_api_module.API), {})
            _VERSION_TO_MIXED_API_CLASS[version] = mixed_class
        return super().__new__(mixed_class, *args)
```

```
>>> from api2 import API
>>> isinstance(Handler(version="2.0"), API)
True
```

---

**Old answer**

Based on your description of "modifying which API class to inherit", you would have to do this (basic implementation as follows):

```py
from __future__ import annotations

import typing as tp

import importlib


if tp.TYPE_CHECKING:
    import types

    APIMetaT = tp.TypeVar("APIMetaT", bound="APIMeta")


class APIMeta(type):
    def __new__(
        mcs: type[APIMetaT],
        name: str,
        bases: tuple[type, ...],
        namespace: dict[str, object],
        /,
        *,
        version: str,
    ) -> APIMetaT:

        versioned_api_module: types.ModuleType = importlib.import_module(
            f"api{version[:version.find('.')]}"
        )
        assert hasattr(versioned_api_module, "API") and isinstance(
            versioned_api_module.API, type
        )
        return super().__new__(mcs, name, (versioned_api_module.API, *bases), namespace)
```

If you had a module whose full name is `api1`, then this would work:

```
>>> class Handler(metaclass=APIMeta, version="1.0"): ...
>>> Handler.mro()
[<class 'Handler'>, <class 'api1.API'>, <class 'object'>]
```

The class variable in your `class API` is not used, because the implementation above is based on matching with module names. You'll have to tweak the implementation if you have a more complex structure (e.g. your `api` module full names are more than just `api<number>`).

Comment: could you please share the instantiation code? How to make a handler instance by given version, for example?

Comment: @aEgoist "Which API class to inherit" has already determined what kind of instance will be created. If you need `version="2.0"`, then `class Handler(metaclass=APIMeta, version="2.0")` will only create instances of `Handler` which inherits from `API` from a module called `api2`. There isn't anything to pass to `__init__`.

Comment: Actually, the version is specified when the handler is to be instantiated. It is not known in the code declaration level, thus `version='2.0'` can only be pass to __init__ or __new__ method.

Comment: @aEgoist OK - I revised it to use `__new__`. You can't do this in `__init__`, because by that time the instance is already created.